# Find specific inverse value of a matrix using the determinant

Tags: linear-algebra

Hello I have this 3x3 matrix

$A=$

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        \cdots & 1 & 2 \\
        2 & \cdots & \cdots \\
        \cdots & -1 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

The determinant is given as $det(A) = -6$

The question is looking for x in the following inverse matrix of A

$A^{-1} =$

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        \cdots & x & \cdots \\
        \cdots & \cdots & \cdots \\
        \cdots & \cdots & \cdots \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

The solution is given as

$\frac{(-1)^{2+1}(1+2)}{det(A)} = -\frac{-3}{-6} = \frac{1}{2} $

but I am not sure where this came from. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You need to find the adjunct matrix $A$, but I am not sure what "..." represents? is it unknown values? where you can compute "..." from $\mathrm{det}A$?

Comment: Yes correct, ... represents unknown values.

Comment: actually looking at it again, you get x by using the cofactor corresponding the second row first column, which you have values for. i.e. $x = -\left| \begin{array}{cc}
1 & 2 \\
-1 & 1 \end{array} \right|$ and then use $A^{-1} = \frac{1}{\mathrm{det}A}adj(A)$

Comment: As suggested below, look up adjugate.

Comment: In particular, you can determine a cofactor of a matrix using $$C_{mn}=(-1)^{m+n}(M_{mn})$$ where $M$ is the determinant of the minor matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It comes from the formula for inverse involving adjugate matrix
$$A^{-1}=\frac1{\det A}\text{adj }A$$

$\text{adj }A = C^\top$, where $C$ is the cofactor matrix of $A$.

You know only the cofactor given by eliminating the column number $0$ the row number $1$, which is $(-1)^{0+1}\left|\begin{matrix}1&2\\-1&1\end{matrix}\right|=-(1+2)=-3.$

By transposing $C$ you see the position of $x$ in $\text{adj }A$ corresponds to the cofactor $-3$. Therefore the $x$ in $A^{-1}$ is $\frac{-3}{\det A}=\frac{-3}{-6}=\frac12$.